# What is the platform string for iPod Touch 6th generation?

Tags: ios, ios8, ipod-touch

What is the platform string for the new iPod Touch, 6th generation (announced today, July 15, 2015)?

My guess is that it's going to be `"iPod6,1"` if it follows the pattern of previous iPod touch models.

(Generally, it's best to query specific hardware capabilities rather than examining the platform string, but in certain cases, it is very helpful to have a lookup table of device characteristics. I make use of the platform string, for example, to determine whether I'm running on a regular-sized iPad or an iPad mini, because the determination cannot be made simply by querying the screen device characteristics. Also, I benchmark my code on multiple iPad devices and know the limitations for each device in terms of computing power, and being able to look up computing power by the platform string avoids having to run a costly benchmark at startup in the production code.)

Answer (score 3):

The new iPod touch appears to be iPod7,1 rather than 6,1 (6,1 must have gone to the same place as Windows 9), according to Matthew Panzarino. See the screenshots here: http://techcrunch.com/2015/07/15/apple-shows-ipod-touch-some-love-with-a8-processors-camera-upgrades-and-new-colors/

Comment: Iiiiinteresting. So I wonder if `iPod6,1` was used on some internal, unreleased iPod Touch? Because the 5th-gen iPod Touch came out 3 years earlier.